# How to check if php is in FCGI mode?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

How can I tell if PHP is running in FCGI mode ?

`phpinfo` , `sapi_name()` returns always `CGI/FCGI` even when running in suPHP mode.

Is it possible to produce a php code that fails/work only with FCGI?

I know it is possible to force suPHP to fail when the script is owned by root, I am looking for the same kind of trick.

EDIT: found "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" in environnement only when i think fcgi is enabled , maybe that is it ?

Comment: What is you actual question? Maybe it would easier to answer that than to speculate on some theory. Have you tried `$_SERVER['GATEWAY_INTERFACE']`? It should return the current mode of execution…

Comment: alwyas give me CGI/1.1 (even with suPHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suPHP runs PHP in CGI mode as a separate process, which is why you see `CGI/FCGI`.

When you run PHP in FastCGI mode, you can set particular environment variables, such as (what you mentioned) `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN`. This could be a way, but you could also modify the FastCGI wrapper script to define your own custom environment variable and test on that.